# QSGGeometryNode depth (z) problems with 3 vertices

Tags: qml, qt5, frustum, scenegraph

I am drawing a 3D geometry (Point3D vertices) in a Qml scene graph with a custom QSGGeometryNode and QSGTransformNode. This works except that the 3D model is cut off at a certain z-coordinate  (z is the depth axis in Qml). First I expected that the problem is due to intersection with the Qml 2D plane. But I tried to move the model along the z axis and it gets always cut off (as if there is a local model frustum clipping plane).

What could be the source of this problem?

Regards,

Comment: So, it cuts always at the same place of the model regardless of where it is?

Comment: Yes. I can rotate the model and it clearly cuts at a certain location.

Comment: I think you're bitten by https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html#mixing-with-3d-primitives . Can you pastebin a small testcase? Can you inspect with tools like `apitrace` or `GammaRay` what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I must have overlooked this page while searching the docs. Probably the easiest way is to go with the ``QQuickPaintedItem`` which has the big disadvantage that it renders into a FBO? I also tried to hijack the OpenGL context (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) but this does not work with mixing Qml. I do not want to use Qt3D due to platform compatibility and QtCanvas3D has huge memory overhead.

Comment: I meant using ``QQuickFramebufferObject`` not ``QQuickPaintedItem``.

Comment: `big disadvantage that it renders into a FBO` well, it's necessary if you want to display truly 3-dimensional content. I wouldn't call it a "big disadvantage"...

Comment: @peppe, if you post your answer with the https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html#mixing-with-3d-primitives link as an answer then I can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't "just" render 3D content inside the scene, as the scene graph will [compress your Z values](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html#mixing-with-3d-primitives) to make them honour proper stacking of the items.

If you have a 3D object, you may want to use [QQuickFramebufferObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickframebufferobject.html) instead (see also [this blog post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/11/integrating-custom-opengl-rendering-with-qt-quick-via-qquickframebufferobject/)).